# Big difference in score (10%) between a split_test_train and a cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I'm on a classification issue with:
2,500 lines.
25000 columns
88 different classes unevenly distributed

And then something very strange happened:

When I run a dozen different split test trains, I always get scores around 60%...

And when I run cross validations, I always get scores around 50%.
Here the screen : [image]
Moreover it has nothing to do with the unequal distribution of classes because when I put a stratify=y on the TTS I stay around 60% and when I put a StratifiedKFold I stay around 50%.

Which score to remember? Why the difference? For me a CV was just a succession of test train splits with different splits from each other, so nothing justifies such a difference in score.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Add shuffle=True to your KFold :
cross_val_score(forest,X,y,cv=KFold(shuffle=True))

Long answer: the difference between a succession of TrainTestSplit and a cross-validation with a classic KFold is that there is a mix in the TTS before the split between the train and the test set.
The difference in score may be due to the fact that your dataset is sorted in a biased way.
So just add shuffle=True to your KFold (or your StratifiedKFold and that's all you need to do).

Answer (score 0):

First sample of code return 5 values, then you learn on 4/5 of the data and valid on 1/5.
Second sample learn on 5/6 and valid on 1/6, and the results are better.

Maybe you can try to do `for k in range(5)` to see if you still have a big diffrence in score ?